# Showing promotional page before Index in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a promotional page / advertisement with video in `ASP.NET MVC` C#, I want to show that page before my `Index.cshtml` called as in RouteConfig. How would I perform this without changing routeConfig, and when I click on skip it should go to `Index.cshtml`

is there any scenario inside `ActionResult` of Index where I can use if else statements?

or anything multiple routing?

Comment: While you are more than welcome to go and create this sort of thing, you should be aware that from January Google will be de-valuing websites that do this sort of thing. [Link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-37178470)

Comment: Have you considered using index.html for the advertisement and then use another name for the current index.html page?

Comment: @DavidG this is not a popup, a complete page, related to hat twebsite

Comment: name doesn't matter

Comment: Yes, but it's something that gets in the way of the real content and Google will potentially mark you down for it.

Comment: well thanks for it

Comment: An introduction/promotion page loaded before main index page for internet use has been discouraged nowadays, since search engines usually determine page rank from site contents. However if you want to make it for intranet, just use simple html page with meta tag to redirect after certain time passed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same using plan HTML, when the page loads initially hide the div which contains your main contents & only show the promotional page inside another div. Once the user hits the skip button, you can toggle both the div to show your main contents.

Comment: I want this only when anyone open the site from start. write url  and hit enter. it shows that page, again close browser or may open new tab again url and enter thois must come

Comment: I don't see there is any issue with this approach.